# Add a field to BibLaTeX output when \ifciteseen is true

Tags: biblatex, citing

I use `biblatex` with verbose and cite via `\footcite{...}` throughout the document.
Problem is: if citing the same source twice, the verbose style outputs author surname and booktitle - but i need it to output author surname and year.

I tried to fix it myself and got so far to change the `verbose.cbx` in
`\\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\cbx`

What I figured out is that (IMHO) is if citeseen is true
`cite:short` or `cite:shorthand` bibmacro will be used.

And I tried to modify

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit*{\nametitledelim}%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
    \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
```

in this file, using `\printfield{year}` and whatnot. However there's no effect, even if I delete all these lines. So I might be on the wrong track after all...

If someone knows more and is willing to help - i'd be glad glad glad :)).

Minimal example (or what I consider to be minimal in my case) below:

```
\documentclass[12p]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[citestyle=verbose, bibstyle=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\bibliography{test}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat
[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
{title}{#1\isdot}
\begin{document}
blala needs a quote \footcite{Schaefers2}\\
quote schaefers2 againt\footcite{Schaefers2}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

with `test.bib` containing

```
@INCOLLECTION{Schaefers2,
author = {Weis, Kurt},
title = {Recht},
editor = {Schäfers, Bernhard},
booktitle = {Grundbegriffe der Soziologie},
publisher = {Leske und Budrich},
adress = {Opladen},
year = {2003},
}
```

Comment: @Audrey yes i noticed this after the (recent?) update to biblatex 2.0 - had problems again for quite a while, but i found what you said on the first pages of the biblatex documentation. biber is now working as well - after reinstall / running all updates there are no version number conflicts anymore... It's likely i'll need some more help soon. However i've learned some things on how to create / modify styles and will first try the possibilities that came to my mind... Guess it will be better to create a new topic for a different problem..?
However, thank you very much, so far.

Answer (score 11):

First of all, you should not alter the files in the main `texmf` tree (i.e. in your MiKTeX tree) directly. Instead, you have different options to modify an existing style; lockstep already gave some hints [in his answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13076/1376) (in the introduction).

To answer your question: `\printdate` is the solution you are looking for (see the biblatex documentation for more details). Hence, the following should work:

**Edit:** As Audrey pointed out, using the `labelyear` and `extrayear` fields instead of `\printdate` avoids ambiguous citations. In order to have these fields available, the option `labelyear=true` must be loaded. Thus, I enhanced my example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  style=verbose,
  labelyear=true,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat
[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
{title}{#1\isdot}
\renewbibmacro*{cite:short}{%
  \printnames{labelname}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
    \printfield{labelyear}\printfield{extrayear}}}

\begin{document}
\footcite{companion,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}

\footcite{companion,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit 2:** Another possibility is to use the options `citestyle=verbose,bibstyle=authoryear` instead of `labelyear=true`. Thereby the `extrayear` field is also printed in the verbose entries. The appearance of the first citations and the bibliography is then, of course, different, giving the year in parentheses right after the name(s):

[image]

Comment: Wow, many many thanks! works like a charm (however i need to omit the option "backend=biber" ..?) many thanks again! :)

Comment: @Martin In `biblatex 2.0` the default option setting is now `backend=biber`. So with this release you'll have to load `biblatex` with `backend=bibtex`. BTW: Feel free to [accept](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/4483)/upvote domwass's answer as it has solved your question.